How do you install python-barcode on Ubuntu 24?
Everywhere I see just use pip but it doesn't work and it isn't found with apt. I think I need to add a repo, which is it?
User@System:~/Desktop$ sudo apt install python3-barcode
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3-barcode
User@System:~/Desktop$ pip install barcode
error:externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.
    
    See /usr/share/doc/python3.12/README.venv for more information.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.


Why do you need it installed system-wide? Usually you should be using a virtual environment instead (python -m venv), but the error message already said that. If you must install it system-wide, read the error message again: you can ignore this check using pip install ... --break-system-packages. barcode isn't packaged as a Ubuntu apt package unlike most popular ones, so apt install python3-barcode won't work, and it's unlikely to be packaged in some third-party apt repoitory  What's exactly your problem?

python3 -m pip install python-barcode
